# LINQ group by with multiple counts

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am having trouble doing multiple counts on a single table in a LINQ query. I am using NHibernate, LINQ to NHibernate and C#.

query is a populated list. I have a table that has a boolean called FullRef. I want to do a LINQ query to give a count of occurances of FullRef = false and FullRef = true on each TrackId. TrackId gets a new row for each time he gets a track.Source == "UserRef".

In the following query I get the correct number count (from the FullRefTrueCount) of FullRef = true, but it gives an unknown wrong number on the FullRefFalseCount.

```
var query2 = from track in query
    where track.Source == "UserRef"
    group track by new { TrackId = track.TrackId, FullRef = track.FullRef } into d

    select new FullReferrer
    {
        Customer = d.Key.TrackId,
        FullRefFalseCount = d.Where(x => x.FullRef == false).Count(),
        FullRefTrueCount = d.Where(x => x.FullRef == true).Count()
    };
```

Anyone have any idea on how to fix it? I am pretty certain the .Where() clause is ignored and the "group by" is screwing me over. 
If I could somehow

```
group track by new { TrackId = track.TrackId, FullRefTrue = track.FullRef, FullRefFalse = !track.FullRef }"
```

it would work. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should group by trackId only, if you want results by trackId...

```
var query2 = query
              .Where(m => m.Source == "UserRef")
              .GroupBy(m => m.TrackId)
              .Select(g => new FullReferrer {
                 Customer = g.Key,
                 FullRefFalseCount = g.Count(x => !x.FullRef),
                 FullRefTrueCount = g.Count(x => x.FullRef)
              });
```